# What is the meaning of local variable hides a field?

Tags: java

So this is just a part of my code, and the entire program compiles and works, but I keep getting "local variable hides a field" next to lines three consecutive lines starting with "GameBoard myBoard = this.getGameBoard();. I'm just curious what that actually means and if it is doing anything to my program in the long run.

```
public void initialze(){
    myBoard = getGameBoard();
    obstacleLocations = myBoard.getObstaclePositions();
    pastureLocations = myBoard.getPasturePositions();

GameBoard myBoard = this.getGameBoard();
    ArrayList<GameLocation> obstacleLocations = myBoard.getObstaclePositions();
    ArrayList<GameLocation> pastureLocations = myBoard.getPasturePositions();
    GameLocation closestPasture = pastureLocations.get(0);
    GameLocation closestObstacle = obstacleLocations.get(0);
```

Comment: It's because you're reusing variable names. Pay attention to your naming and prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It means you've got two different variables with the same name - `myBoard`.  One of them is a field in your class.  Another one is a local variable, that is, one that you've declared inside a method.

It's a bad idea to have two variables with the same name.  It can make your code very confusing and difficult to maintain.

Comment: So is a solution to simply remove the variables inside either the method or class and just have them contained in one of the two?

Comment: No, just give them different names

Comment: It depends what `getGameBoard()` does.  If all it does is `return myBoard`, then you should remove both the lines `myBoard = getGameBoard();` (which does nothing) and `GameBoard myBoard = getGameBoard();` (which is the line that's causing your problem).

Comment: On the other hand, if `getGameBoard()` does something other than `return myBoard;`, then you probably want to keep the first line, and throw away `GameBoard myBoard = getGameBoard();`.

Comment: It would have been so much simpler if the IDE could say "Looks like you've got two different variables with the same name" instead of "local variable hides a field" which makes no sense.

Answer (score 5):

The local variable in a method is always the variable with the highest visibility. That's why in a class setter you always do something like:

```
void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

The `this.id` tells Java to assign the `id` (from the parameter) to the field variable. That's why this will not work:

```
void setId(String id) {
    id = id;
}
```

Since it'll assign `id` to itself.

You can read about scope, see: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html for an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot; appreciate it.

Comment: You can always vote up an answer that you find useful and accept any answer of your question that seems to answer correctly your problem.