# Variables in java

Tags: java, parameters

I'm beginner learner of Java.

Why does this code work as normal:

```
public class world{
 static int i=1
public static void main(String args[]){
 System.out.print(i+",");
          m();
          m();
System.out.print(i);}
public static void m(){
         i+=2;
}}
```

while this code does work differently:

```
public class world{
      static int i=1
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.print(i+",");
          m(i);
          m(i);
   System.out.print(i);}
public static void m(int i){
           i+=2;
}}
```

Please explain this question.

Comment: Time to learn how to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: *please explain this question*    - Where is your question?

Comment: You can have only public class in one .java file.

Comment: @suvojit_007 I don't think he's actually using two classes in the same file, he's just showing us the two different files all together.

Comment: @CyanCoding now it's fine but there were two public classes before the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you have declared a local variable in the second block, with the same name as the static variable.

So `i` in `i += 2;` in the second block is updating the `i` passed to the method, and not the static field.

So each call to `m(i);` will update `i` to 3, then do nothing with it. Confirm by adding `System.out.println(i);` to the method and they will both print `3`.

If you wanted to update the static variable in the second method, you could use `world.i += 2;`.

**[Example](https://ideone.com/tiJ4bZ)**

Comment: In your example why we have to call ideone.i+=2 while first block habe only i+=2.please explain these.                                             And second block output is 1,1 but why you mention it as 1,3?

Comment: @Tilak I did explain what’s happening in the second block. The method updates `i` passed to it and not the `static int i`.

Comment: Thank you very much.I can understand now.

Comment: I want one more clarification please. why method updates variable i passed to static i in first block and not in second block.

Comment: @Tilak in the first one, you don’t pass anything to `m()`, and then `i+=2;` updates the `static int i`, in the second you pass the value of `static int i` when you write `m(i)` and the method takes `int i` as an argument and then `i+=2;` updates the `int i` passed to it, and not the `static int i`. Have a google of *local variable hides field* or read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832466/what-is-the-meaning-of-local-variable-hides-a-field).